How to create a start and stop control in Python?
I'm trying to create a control for loops in Python that starts and stops a loop at any time.
I have a start() function, from then on the script starts running in the python terminal, however I would like that when I write stop, it stops the loop, but without ending the entire program.
example:
loop = True

def start():
    for i in loop:
        print('loop..')
        print('loop..')
        # is constantly displaying things in the terminal and executing commands..
        
        if condition:
            loop = False
            # stops the loop, but can be started again at any time

print('stopped')

It would be something similar to the code below, which doesn't work as it should because it keeps running infinitely, even if I write controll('stop')
import time

def controll(status):
    global loop_started 

    if status == 'start':
        print("starting loop...")
        loop_started = True
        starting_loop()

    elif status == 'stop':
        print("stoping loop...")
        loop_started = False

    else:
        print("invalid")

def starting_loop():
    while loop_started:
        print("loop started...")
        time.sleep(1)


loop_started = False


controll('start')  # start the loop
time.sleep(5) 
controll('stop')  # stop the loop

How can I create this control in a functional way?

What were you hoping for i in loop would achieve (apart from a TypeError)?

@SIGHUP I wrote this excerpt in a 'playful' way to exemplify what I would like to do, the real code is the second one  :)

import threading
import time

# Global variable to control the loop
running = True

def loop_function():
    global running
    while running:
        print("Looping...")
        time.sleep(1)

def start_loop():
    global running
    running = True
    print("Loop started.")
    # Start a new thread for the loop
    loop_thread = threading.Thread(target=loop_function)
    loop_thread.start()

def stop_loop():
    global running
    running = False
    print("Loop stopped.")

def main():
    while True:
        user_input = input("Type 'start' to start the loop or 'stop' to stop it: ")
        if user_input == 'start':
            start_loop()
        elif user_input == 'stop':
            stop_loop()
        else:
            print("Invalid input. Please type 'start' or 'stop'.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


If you wish a function that you can stop and resume instead of stop an restart, you can use an event to control it.
from threading import Thread, Event
import itertools
from time import sleep

stop_loop = False
def loop(loop_running):
    loop_running.set()
    for i in itertools.count(start=1):
        if stop_loop:
            break
        loop_running.wait()
        print(f"loop #{i}")
        sleep(1)

loop_running = Event()
thread = Thread(target=loop, args=(loop_running,))
print("Starting")
thread.start()
sleep(2.5)
print("Pausing")
loop_running.clear()
sleep(3)
print("Resuming")
loop_running.set()
sleep(2.5)
print("Ending")
stop_loop = True
thread.join()


Your "looping" activity needs to be in a thread or subprocess. Answers show how you could do this with a thread. Here's how you could do it with a subprocess:
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
from time import sleep

def run_loop(event):
    # continue for as long as event is set
    while event.is_set():
        sleep(1)
    print("Stopping")

def main():
    with Manager() as manager:
        (event := manager.Event()).set()
        (proc := Process(target=run_loop, args=(event,))).start()
        while True:
            response = input("Enter a command: ")
            if response == "stop":
                event.clear()
                proc.join()
                break
            # process the input command here
            print(f"Processing {response}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

